# How do I count in a left join query

Tags: mysql

How do I count the number of participants in the event_participants table. This is my table

```
event_place

id | name     
1  | New York 
2  | Canada   


event_participants

id | event_place_id | name
1  | 1              | Jon
2  | 1              | Mike
3  | 2              | Van
```

and I am getting a wrong result on my query

```
SELECT count(*) as count
FROM event_participants as t1
LEFT JOIN event_place as t2
ON t1.event_place_id = t2.id;
```

and the result is 3

I should be getting a result like this

```
New York | 2
Canada   | 1
```

Comment: Research group by

Comment: You could use the `GROUP BY` [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

your query like this.

```
select pl.id,pl.name,count(*) from
event_place pl 
left join event_participants ep 
on pl.id = ep.event_place_id 
group by pl.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting correct results because you are counting all the records.

If you want the counts per event place, you should GROUP BY event place

```
SELECT t1.event_place_id, t2.name, count(*) as count
FROM event_participants as t1
LEFT JOIN event_place as t2
ON t1.event_place_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.event_place_id, t2.name,;
```

Comment: how do i display the 0 results also

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, count(1) from event_place a, event_participants b
where b.event_place_id = a.id
group by a.name;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a couple of issues.

I presume you want a list of all the even places, and the number of people at each one. If so that suggests that you need to LEFT OUTER JOIN the event_participants table to the event_place table, rather than the other way round. This way you can have places listed which have no participants.

You also need a GROUP BY clause.

And if you use COUNT(*) you are counting the returned rows (prior to the grouping). However if there is no matching participants then a row is still returned for the place, hence you would get 1 as the count. To avoid this specify a column in the COUNT() which is on the participants table. COUNT with a column name counts the number of non NULL values of that column, hence if no participants it will return 0 for that place:-

```
SELECT t2.name,
    COUNT(t1.id) AS count
FROM event_place t2
LEFT JOIN event_participants t1
ON t1.event_place_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.name
```